# What is the purpose of mockMvc .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)?

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I don't understand the point of this method and can't find any info about it. What is the reason of using it, especially for void methods like in example below? I've tried deleting it in my tests and seems like everything is the same.
Test

```
   @Test
public void deletePatientById_success() throws Exception {
    Mockito.when(patientRecordRepository.findById(RECORD_2.getPatientId())).thenReturn(Optional.of(RECORD_2));

    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
            .delete("/patient/2")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Controller to be tested

```
    @DeleteMapping(value = "{patientId}")
public void deletePatientById(@PathVariable(value = "patientId") Long patientId) throws NotFoundException {
    if (patientRecordRepository.findById(patientId).isEmpty()) {
        throw new NotFoundException("Patient with ID " + patientId + " does not exist.");
    }
    patientRecordRepository.deleteById(patientId);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `contentType` method does not belong to the `mockMvc` class but to the [`MockHttpServletRequestBuilder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.html#contentType-org.springframework.http.MediaType-) class and it sets the 'Content-Type' header of the request to a specific type (in this case you inform the endpoint that the request body format of your request is JSON).

Comment: Thank you, so If I test delete operation there is no point of setting Content type as I have no content in my body. Is it right?

Comment: @Henry_Muller You are welcome.  You are absolutely correct because in your delete controller the only read value is the id from the query string (no body content read), so there is no reason to use it.  The content-type header is just an indication for the endpoint, but the endpoint can ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

This basically sets the `Content-Type` header of the request (in your case JSON).

Check for additional information in https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.html#contentType-org.springframework.http.MediaType-